# TeamCity compile fails while local compile works

Tags: c#, oracle, tfs, teamcity-8.0

I'm not exactly a master of TeamCity (yet!) so please accept my apologies if this question is poorly formulated.

In my local IDE I can rebuild the solution. In TeamCity, I can do that too. Then, I add a new project, which has a reference to an external DLL (*Oracle.DataAccess*). While the local version builds without problems, I now get an error when running the build from TeamCity.

It claims that the problem is as follows.

> error CS0012:
>   The type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess,
>   Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.

1. Why does it complain about it when the local rebuild works?
2. What can be done about it?

I've checked that I'm targeting the correct repository to avoid [this mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263269/1525840). The only thing that changes is that I'm adding the project to the solution. I also noticed that removing the reference from the project fails the local build with the same message as the TC's. However, readding the reference to it (followed by a check-in) doesn't reciprocate the success of rebuild...

Suggestions?!

Comment: Make a folder in your project "libs" that contains all the libraries you use.  Check them into the SVN and try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that reference to Oracle.DataAccess has attribute CopyLocal = true.

Also, take a look at the other properties as well. The path might be set to a locally available drive pointing to a file that isn't checked in to the VCS.

Comment: You can set it in Visual Studio, right click on the reference , select Properties, and in the properties panel set Copy Local = True

Comment: Thanks - as I wrote I've found that. However, you might just have helped me anyway. I just saw that the path of the little #¤%&er is set to local *C:\Oracle\...*!

Comment: Edit your reply to include what I wrote (and combine it with the comment made by Dean) and I'll check you green as an answer. +1 in any case!

Comment: Hahaha, no worries Konrad, this is not a contest, thanks for wanting to give credit, but it's not important to me... Happy coding!

Comment: I like your attitude. However, I prefer to close the questions I ask if there's some guidance provided. In this case, there is but it's - sort of - half in the reply and half in the comments, which can make it harder for a future (and lazy-ish) reader to get. I'll take the liberty of editing your reply before accepting it, then.   :)